# Create .php files with fopen()

Tags: php

I'm trying this:

```
<a href="
<?php
$fl= $p['n'].".php";
$fh = fopen($fl, 'w') or die("Can't create file");
if($fh)
{
$code ="
<?php
// html and php combined code (the php is for sessions)
?>";
echo fwrite($file,$code); 
    fclose($file); 
}?>"></a>
```

The problem is that the codes inside `$code` are being evaluated and I need that `$code` simply save the codes like a string.

Comment: You probably want to quote that file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [PHP's nowdoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) feature (emphasis mine):

> Nowdocs are to single-quoted strings what heredocs are to double-quoted strings. A nowdoc is specified similarly to a heredoc, but no parsing is done inside a nowdoc. **The construct is ideal for embedding PHP code or other large blocks of text without the need for escaping**.

#### Example

```php
<?php

$test_var = 1;

$str = <<<'EOD'
Example of string
spanning multiple lines
using nowdoc syntax.
$test_var
EOD;

echo $str;
```

Outputs

```
Example of string
spanning multiple lines
using nowdoc syntax.
$test_var
```

---

So this ...

```
<a href="
<?php
$fh = fopen($p['n'].'.php', 'w') or die("Can't create file");
if($fh)
{
$code = <<<'EOD'
<?php
// html and php combined code (the php is for sessions)
?>"
EOD;
echo fwrite($file,$code); 
fclose($file); 
}?>"></a>
```

... should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Using `"$foo"` will evaluate, but `'$foo'` will not.

However, this is opens massive security risks so I would probably back up and take a look at what you’re trying to do.